# Issue with reading pixel RGB values in OpenCL

Tags: c++, c, image, image-processing, opencl

I need to read pixels from two parts (with same width and height) of image ( e.g. squares ([0,0], [300, 300]) and ([400,0], [700,300])) and make difference for each pixel.

This is **C (pseudo)code**:

```
/**
 * @param img Input image
 * @param pos Integer position of top left corner of the second square (in this case 400)
 */
double getSum(Image& img, int pos)
{
    const int width_of_cut = 300;
    int right_bottom = pos + width;

    Rgb first, second;
    double ret_val = 0.0;

    for(int i=0; i < width_of_cut; i++)
    {
        for(int j=0; j < width_of_cut; j++)
        {
            first  = img.getPixel( i, j );
            second = img.getPixel( i + pos, j );

            ret_val += ( first.R - second.R ) +
                       ( first.G - second.G ) +
                       ( first.B - second.B );
        }
    }

    return ret_val;
}
```

But my **kernel** (with same arguments and the `__global float* output` is set to 0.0 in host code) is giving me completely different values:

```
__constant sampler_t sampler = CLK_NORMALIZED_COORDS_FALSE |
                               CLK_ADDRESS_CLAMP_TO_EDGE |
                               CLK_FILTER_NEAREST;



__kernel void getSum( __read_only image2d_t input,
                        const int x_coord,
                      __global float* output )
{
    int width  = get_image_width( input );
    int height = get_image_height( input );

    int2 pixelcoord = (int2) (get_global_id(0), get_global_id(1)); // image coordinates

    const int width_of_cut = 300; 

    const int right_bottom = x_coord + width_of_cut;

    int a,b;
    a = (int)(pixelcoord.x + x_coord);
    b = pixelcoord.y; 

    if( a < right_bottom && b < width_of_cut )
    {
        float4 first = read_imagef(input, sampler, pixelcoord);
        float4 second = read_imagef(input, sampler, (int2)(a,b));

        output[get_global_id(0)] += ((first.x - second.x) +
                                    (first.y - second.y) +
                                    (first.z - second.z));
    }

}
```

I am new to OpenCL and I have no idea what am I doing wrong.

### Update (1d image):

I changed the kernel code. Now I'm reading an 1d image in one loop, but I'm still not getting the correct values. I'm not sure that I know, how to read pixels from 1d image correctly.

```
__kernel void getSum( __read_only image1d_t input,
                        const int x_coord,
                      __global float* output,
                        const int img_width )
{

    const int width_of_cut = 300; 

    int i = (int)(get_global_id(0));

    for(int j=0; j < width_of_cut; j++)
    {
        int f = ( img_width*i + j );
        int s = f + x_coord;

        float4 first = read_imagef( input, sampler, f ); //pixel from 1st sq.
        float4 second = read_imagef( input, sampler, s ); //pixel from 2nd sq.

        output[get_global_id(0)] += ((first.x - second.x) +
                                     (first.y - second.y) +
                                     (first.z - second.z));
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Race condition.

All vertical work items are accessing the same output memory (`output[get_global_id(0)] +=`) and not atomically. Therefore the result are likely incorrect (e.g., two threads read the same value, add something to it, and write it back. Only one wins).

If your device supports it, you could make this an atomic operation, but it would be slow. You'd be better off running a 1D kernel that has a loop accumulating these vertically (so, the `j` loop from your C example).

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I **updated my post** - I tried to change my kernel code as you suggested, but I'm not sure that I am reading (indexing) image pixels correctly. Could you please tell me, where the mistake is?

Comment: Looks about right, but why did you use a 1D image? It looks like your original code was 2D. Therefore I would think you would use a 2D image in your kernel.